# React Router v4 Match transitions using React Motion

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-motion

I'm loving RR4 and RM, there's already great examples for React Router V4 (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v4/website/examples) but i'm struggling to understand how I can use the new V4 API to transition between different Matches in my Router with React Motion, fading in and out between my 'pages'.

I've tried to understand how the Transition example works with the MatchWithFade but I'm missing how to take this and apply it to multiple matches representing my page structure.

As an example: given two routes setup in my Router how can I have the mounting and unmounting handled by react-motion with TransitionMotion?

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Match pattern="/products" component={Products} />
    <Match pattern="/accessories" component={Accessories} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the linked example we can simplify. First we create a wrapper component that will replace the `<Match/>` tag and wrap it's component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Match } from 'react-router'
import { TransitionMotion, spring } from 'react-motion'

const styles = {}

styles.fill = {
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0
}

const MatchTransition = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const willLeave = () => ({ zIndex: 1, opacity: spring(0) })

  return (
    <Match {...rest} children={({ matched, ...props }) => (
      <TransitionMotion
        willLeave={willLeave}
        styles={matched ? [ {
          key: props.location.pathname,
          style: { opacity: 1 },
          data: props
        } ] : []}
      >
        {interpolatedStyles => (
          <div>
            {interpolatedStyles.map(config => (
              <div
                key={config.key}
                style={{ ...styles.fill, ...config.style }}
              >
                <Component {...config.data} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </TransitionMotion>
    )} />
  )
}

export default MatchTransition
```

Then we use it like this:

```
<MatchTransition pattern='/here' component={About} />
<MatchTransition pattern='/there' component={Home} />
```

Comment: Thanks @yashua but that's the example I referred to in my post. The question is how to do something similar but for transitioning between two different Matches like in my example. It's perhaps just my lack of understaning of how react-motion works.

Comment: Duh... face slap. So are you basically just wanting to see how the example you linked to would be applied in your case? Without all the colorized glory?

Comment: Ah I see, I was trying to use a single TransitionMotion but I can see from your example that I would need to use two. I'll give it a try, thanks for your help!

Comment: @PaulCrabtree were you ever able to figure this out? I'm wondering the same thing