# Nested Match routes with React Router v4 and MatchWithFade

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-motion

This question is a follow-up to this:

[Trouble with React Router v4 and MatchWithFade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291288/trouble-with-react-router-v4-and-matchwithfade/41308351#41308351)

I've got another (potentially silly) question about using `MatchWithFade` and React Router v4. What I'd like to do is have nested routes, so a top-level component might have this:

`<MatchWithFade pattern='/one' component={One} />`

...and then `One` might have this:

`<Match pattern='/one/one' Component={OneOne} />`

This doesn't strike me as an unusual pattern (though maybe it is). In any event, the behavior I'm observing is that, using the above example, if I load `OneOne`, it gets mounted, and then `componentWillUnmount` is immediately called. Had I to guess, I'd say that `TransitionMotion` is keeping track of a (perhaps hidden) instance of `OneOne`, and once the transition is complete, it unmounts that hidden component. As far as the basic UI is concerned, `OneOne` is rendered. However, if `componentWillUnmount` does any cleanup (like, say, removing something from Redux), then of course that action is fired, and any data tied to `OneOne` is blown away.

Here's a complete example that illustrates the problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router/BrowserRouter'

import { TransitionMotion, spring } from 'react-motion'
import Match from 'react-router/Match'
import Link from 'react-router/Link';

const styles = {
  fill: { position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0 }
};

const MatchWithFade = ({ component:Component, ...rest }) => {
  const willLeave = () => ({ zIndex: 1, opacity: spring(0) })

  return (
    <Match {...rest} children={({ matched, ...props }) => {
      return (
        <TransitionMotion
          willLeave={willLeave}
          styles={matched ? [ {
            key: props.location.pathname,
            style: { opacity: 1 },
            data: props
          } ] : []}
        >
          {interpolatedStyles => {
            return (
              <div>
                {interpolatedStyles.map(config => (
                  <div
                    key={config.key}
                    style={{...styles.fill, ...config.style }}>
                    <Component {...config.data}/>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            )
          }}
        </TransitionMotion>
      )
    }}/>
  )
}

const TwoOne = () => {
  return (
    <div>Two One</div>
  )
}


class TwoTwo extends Component {
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("TwoTwo will unmount")
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>Two Two</div>
    )
  }
}


const TwoHome = () => {
  return (
    <div>Two Home</div>
  )
}


class One extends Component {
  componentWillUnmount () {
    console.log("ONE UNMOUNTING")
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 300, border: '1px solid black', backgroundColor: 'orange', minHeight: 200}}>
        One one one one one one one one one one<br />
        One one one one one one one one one one<br />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Two = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 300, border: '1px solid black', backgroundColor: 'yellow', minHeight: 200}}>
      <Match pattern='/two/one' component={TwoOne} />
      <Match pattern='/two/two' component={TwoTwo} />
      <Match pattern='/two(/)?' exactly={true} component={TwoHome} />
    </div>
  )
}


class App extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div style={{padding: 12}}>
            <div style={{marginBottom: 12}}>
              <Link to='/one'>One</Link> || <Link to='/two'>Two</Link>
              || <Link to='/two/one'>Two One</Link>
              || <Link to='/two/two'>Two Two</Link>
            </div>
            <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
              <MatchWithFade pattern='/one' component={One} />
              <MatchWithFade pattern='/two' component={Two} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you load this and open a console, toggle between the `One` and `Two` links. You'll see the cross fade happen in the UI, and you'll see "ONE UNMOUNTING" in the console when the transition from One to Two completes. So that's right.

Now, click between `Two One` and `Two Two`. In this case, when `Two One` is clicked, you'll immediately see "TwoTwo will unmount" in the console, which is good. However, if you click `Two Two`, you'll see "TwoTwo will unmount" after about a second--which I take to be the amount of time the parent `MatchWithFade` takes to execute.

So I'm not sure what's going on here. Is my code just busted? Am I doing something that RRv4 cannot support? Have I uncovered a bug?

Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your use of `props.location.pathname` as a key. This should always be the same for a component, but the way that you have written it, it changes each time that you navigate. Try changing this:

```
const styles = {
  fill: { position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0 }
};
```

to:

```
const styles = {
  fill: { position: 'relative', top: 0, left: 0 }
};
```

and you will see that you are rendering two instances of `<Two>` (one for each key).

If you were to use a constant `key`, such as `rest.pattern` (the pattern associated with this `<Match>`), your issue would go away.

```
styles={matched ? [ {
  key: rest.pattern,
  style: { opacity: 1 },
  data: props
} ] : []}
```

Comment: Ah! Interesting! The `MatchWithFade` code was taken verbatim from the React-Router docs, so I assumed it was exactly as it should be. And now I see the difference between `props.location.pathname` and `rest.pattern`. `rest.pattern` is the part of the path that matches up to the current `Match` component, and `props.location.pathname` is the complete path, which means yes, the key changes, and so multiple instances are loaded. So this probably means that the RR docs should be updated to use `rest.pattern` rather than `props.location.pathname`, so others don't run into this issue.

Comment: It can be a little complicated to reason about, but the way that I think about it is this: 1) Each `<TransitionMotion>` is unique. If you have two, that is two different animations. 2) An element is created for each key in a `<TransitionMotion>`. In the docs example, a new `<HSL>` should be rendered for each location, so using `props.location.pathname` works well as the key. In your code, you only want one `<Two>` rendered, so you need a key that does not change.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. And yes, it is a little hard to get my head around all of it, but it's starting to seep in. To be clear, in their example, `rest.pattern` would work as a key, just as props.location.pathname` does, right? And it has the added advantage of being a little more idiot-proof, in that somebody (like, oh, me) could swipe that code and modify it, and not worry about changing that key.

Comment: No it would not. There is only one pattern (`/:h/:s/:l`) in the example, so changing locations would not create a new element like having the key tied to `props.location.pathname` does. In your code, you basically have two animations: the first is the entry and exit of `<One>` and the second is the entry and exit of `<Two>`. Realistically these should be part of the same `<TransitionMotion>`. In the current alpha, this is a pain point, but I believe that it will be easier in the upcoming beta by using the `<Switch>` component. (I haven't tried it yet, but I am fairly certain.)

Comment: Oh, is that because the pattern here has variables? (e.g. `:h`, etc) I assume  if they were hard-coded paths like my example, then rest.pattern would work. I'm eager to try the upcoming beta. I understand significant changes have been made. Any idea when that'll be released?

Comment: Yes. The pathnames `/10/20/30`, `/0/0/0`, and `/100/750/50` should each create a new `<HSL>`, which making the pathname the key will do. If the key was the pattern, then changing pathnames would not create a new `<HSL>` element but instead replace the props of the existing one (like React normally does).